# Does $X_n \xrightarrow{\mathbb P} c \in \mathbb R$ imply $\phi(X_n) \xrightarrow{\mathbb P} \phi(c)$ in this case?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, continuity, random-variables

> Let $X_n \xrightarrow{\mathbb P} c \in \mathbb R$ and $\phi: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be bounded, continuous in $c$, and $\phi(c)=0$. Show that $\mathbb E\left[\phi(X_n)\right]\to0.$

I was going to apply the dominated convergence theorem. And the only thing which seems to be missing is $\phi(X_n) \xrightarrow{\mathbb P} \phi(c)$. Is it possible to show it without using the [continuous mapping theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem#Convergence_in_probability)?

Any hints are very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liu Gang's answer is correct. We can also proceed more directly: fix $\varepsilon$; there is some positive $\delta$ such that if $|x-c|\lt \delta$, then $|\phi(x)|\lt\varepsilon$. We thus have 
$$|\mathbb E[\phi(X_n)]|\leqslant \mathbb E[|\phi(X_n)|\chi\{|X_n-X|\lt\delta\}]+\mathbb E[|\phi(X_n)|\chi\{|X_n-X|\geqslant\delta\}]\\
\leqslant \varepsilon+\sup_{t\in\mathbb R}|\phi(t)|\cdot \mu\{|X_n-X|\geqslant\delta\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You can use the fact: A $\iff$  B, where A and B are respectively:

A: $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability

B: from any subsequence of $X_n$, we can subtract a sub-subsequence which converges almost surely to $X$.

Actually we can use this property to prove your conclusion.

Suppose $E\phi(X_n)$ does not converge to $0$, then there exists $\epsilon >0$ and $\{n_k\}$ such that $|E\phi(X_{n_k})| > \epsilon$.

From ${X_{n_k}}$ we can subtract a sub-subsequence $X_{n_{k_l}}$ which convergs to $c$ almost surely. Then by dominated convergence and the continuity of $\phi$ at $c$, we get $$\lim_{ l\to 0} E\phi(X_{n_{k_l}}) = \phi(c) = 0$$

which is contradictory with $|E\phi(X_{n_{k_l}})| > \epsilon$